# Sphero 2.0 RollCommand Is not working continuos

Tags: sphero-api, sphero

maybe I'm getting something wrong but if I send the RollCommand it will only move a little after a sec. it will stop.

In the QuickStart guide there is an information that it will roll until it hits something or it gets out of range.

What I'm not getting here?
Do I have to repeat my function every second?

```
-(void)rollforward{
[RKRollCommand sendCommandWithHeading:90 velocity:0.5];}
```

Comment: That command should cause the robot to drive indefinitely.  Are you sure there is not a timer in your code stopping the robot?  Also - Check out the Button Drive Sample.

Comment: I've tried a timer function but it has no effect at all every time the same distance depending on velocity value. But I use the Mac API maybe it's different there.

Comment: I just checked same issue. I've taken the hello world sample added one button and it drives about 0.5m ca. 1sec then it stops. The only thing in the button pressed function is the roll command u can see above.

Comment: Can maybe someone try this. I use ios7 iPhone 4s Github sample hello world with one additional button and roll command.(button drive app crashes every time)

Answer (score 0):

This is called **Motion Timeout**. It's one of five option flags which can be set since Firmware 1.20. These flags keep their state even after sphero is switched off.

More information on how to set and get the flags can be found on these sample projects:

- **iOS:** https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-iOS-SDK/tree/master/samples/OptionFlags
- **Android:** https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-Android-SDK/tree/master/samples/OptionFlags

The documentation says this flag is off by default but maybe they changed this in a prior firmare update.